# How to stop a WatchService by pressing a Button in another JFrame?

Tags: java, button, iteration, break, watchservice

I'm a complete noob in java programming and StackOverflow and I always found the answers for my questions by lurking and searching for topics my issues could relate to but it seems I can't find anything that can help me right now.

Basically I have a WatchService which is monitoring a folder of my choice until a file named "a.txt" or "b.txt" is created. However, I'd want a button in another JFrame to create this "a.txt" button.

The rest of the program is actually fine and everything works except when I try to click this button which it becomes "unpressable" when the watchservice starts.

I have tried to use threads but I could not make them work.

Can someone explain me better where I am making mistakes?
Thank you all so much. 
Here is some of my code for better understanding.

This is the method that watches if the file gets created.

```
 String filepath = cfg.getProperty("outFolder");
        Path folder = Paths.get(filepath);
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        folder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        boolean valid = true;
                outerloop:
        do {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                                        if(fileName.equals("a.txt"))
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("File found:" + fileName);
                                            break outerloop;
                                        }

                }
            }

            valid = watchKey.reset();

        } while (valid);
```

Instead, this, is the method that the button that creates the file would call if I pressed it, but I can't seem to press while the monitor is going.

```
private void createCancelFile() throws IOException {
            String cancelPath = "a.txt";
            f = new File(cancelPath);
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
            if(f.createNewFile())
            {
                wasThere=false;
                isCreated=true;
            }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While the code you posted is not a [mcve], I'm guessing you need to run the `WatchService` in a background thread. Do you know about class [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)?

Comment: Abra is right.  Swing runs in a single thread.  Every ActionListener (and all listeners) are invoked in that thread.  Your loop is preventing that thread from proceeding, so no other events are processed.  Not mouse input, not keyboard input, not paint events.  You must place your loop in the `run` method of a Runnable (or the `call` method of a Callable), and invoke that Runnable in a different thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abra! I fixed the issue in no time thanks to your suggestion. I didn't know about SwingWorker until your comment so thank you very much! And thanks a loto also to @VGR for explaining me how listeners work in java. I'm self-teaching myself programming and I actually found myself in a situation pretty harder than I thought but thanks to you I managed to fix it. Thanks again guys!